# Java Contracts - Client Use & Preconditions

Tags: java, client, contract

The following homework question has both me (and the TA that I asked about it) confused:

> Note the requires clause for the power method, specifically the
>   following assertion:
>   ***Integer.MIN_VALUE <= n ^ (p) <= Integer.MAX_VALUE***
>
> - What happens if the client violates this precondition?
> - Is it possible that a legal call to the root method will violate the requires clause for the power method?
> - How could the client check the precondition of power?

This seems like a trick question to me the given power method returns the result of `n^(p)`, with n being the lone parameter of the function.

The requires clause is meant to be fulfilled by the client (one calling the function), but how can the client know if `n^(p)` will be within the bounds of an integer type if the entire point of calling the method is to calculate `n^(p)`? All the client knows before method return is the value of `n`.
Clearly if the client violates this precondition we'll get an overflow and rollback.

Then, looking at the second bullet point, the client could indeed pass in an argument n that is within the bounds of type int but then exceeds that once powered. However, since the precondition would then be violated this is technically not a legal call?

Lastly, how can the client check the precondition of power if the check of that precondition is the entire point of calling the power method to begin with?

Comment: What _power method_ is there talked about?

Comment: @Armali The power method itself isn't really important in this case. Its just a method that takes in argument n and returns n^p. My question is moreso to the point of said method's contract.